# Scala list of tuples match

Tags: scala

I have following list

```
val listA = List(("tcp",22,"All","sshd"), ("tcp6",22,"All","sshd"), ("tcp6",443,"All","docker-proxy"), ("tcp6",8000,"All","docker-proxy"), ("tcp6",4100,"All","docker-proxy"), ("tcp6",5000,"All","docker-proxy"), ("tcp",5000,"All","docker-proxy"),("tcp6",4200,"All","docker-proxy"), ("tcp6",80,"All","docker-proxy"))
```

Type of `listA` as `List[(String, Int, String, String)]` and my expected output as

```
val output = List(("tcp",22,"All","sshd"), ("tcp6",443,"All","docker-proxy"), ("tcp6",8000,"All","docker-proxy"), ("tcp6",4100,"All","docker-proxy"), ("tcp6",5000,"All","docker-proxy"), ("tcp6",4200,"All","docker-proxy"), ("tcp6",80,"All","docker-proxy"))
```

Here want to match `listA.map(_._2) distinct` I tried following

```
val output = listA.groupBy(_._2).map {
  case (key, value) =>
  if (value.map(_._2).contains(key)) {
    value
  }
}
```

but above not give me expected results ( it shows same as listA ).

How to get expected output any one knows?

Comment: If somebody helps you, try marking their answers as correct!

Comment: @mohit where you find out I am not accepting answer or marking as correct

Comment: @mohit I think you was not checking very well I accepted answers as well as up voted. And maybe this discussion not related to my question.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you want to achieve, than this is what you need

```
listA.groupBy(_._2).map{ case (_, value) => value.head }
```

It picks the first element from each port-group.

Comment: oho it's my bad I miss very small thing. thnks